# One-Hot Encoding in Scikit-learn for only part of the DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am trying to use a decision tree classier on my data which looks very similar to the data in this tutorial: https://www.ritchieng.com/machinelearning-one-hot-encoding/
[image]

The tutorial then goes on convert the strings into numeric data:

```
X = pd.read_csv('titanic_data.csv')
X = X.select_dtypes(include=[object])
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
X_2 = X.apply(le.fit_transform)
```

This leaves the DataFrame looking like this:

[image]

After this, the data is put through the OneHotEncoder and I assume can then be split and passed into a decision tree classier fairly easily.

The problem is that it appears to me that the original numeric data gets lots through this process of encoding. How can I keep or add in later the numeric data that was removed during the encoding process? Thanks!

Comment: Onehotencoder has a `categorical_features`  parameter

Comment: you can keep the index and merge the two dataframes together?

Comment: @VnC would I do that before or after OneHotEncoder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is a really simple solution - using [`pd.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)

If you have a Data Frame like the following:

```
so_data = {
    'passenger_id': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'survived': [1,0,0,1,0],
    'age': [24,25,68,39,5],
    'sex': ['female', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'female'],
    'first_name': ['Joanne', 'Mark', 'Josh', 'Petka', 'Ariel']
}
so_df = pd.DataFrame(so_data)
```

which looks like:

```
    passenger_id    survived    age   sex       first_name
0              1           1    24  female        Joanne
1              2           0    25  male          Mark
2              3           0    68  male          Josh
3              4           1    39  female        Petka
4              5           0    5   female        Ariel
```

**You can just do:**

```
pd.get_dummies(so_df)
```

which will give you:

[image]

(sorry for the screenshot, but it's really difficult to clean the df on SO)

Comment: When I split my dataset I use X = pima[feature_cols] (# Features), 
y = pima.destination( # Target variable) I must set feature_cols equal to all of my feature column names. pd.get_dummies returns lots of columns which I don't want to have to manually enter. Do you know away around this?

Comment: `feature_cols = df.drop(target_col, axis=1).columns` - this will return all of them. If you don't want them all you can apply some regex or something else to get the ones you want.

Comment: I suppose the best would be to split features and labels beforehand (including the features that you'd need only), then apply the `get_dummies()` and then `feature_cols = X_df.columns`